# Consolidating 2 Application Servers to just 1

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, server-farm, windows-server, server

I'd like to consolidate our current 2 application servers to just one, due to license compliance.

The result of that final SharePoint 2013 farm architecture would ideally be - 1 WFE, 1 App, 1 SQLDB & 1 Office web app Server

Attached is a screenshot of specs
[image]

What would be some key points to look out for?

Answer (score 0):

When the docs state the minimum memory requirements, that applies to running the base SharePoint install. On top of that, you're running PowerPivot. PowerPivot models run in-memory, and so can be quite problematic if there are a number of large workbooks competing for memory with your other SP services.

Along those lines, search is also sized separately, depending on the number of files being indexed, etc.

Comment: As long as PowerPivot is running on a separate SSAS box, this should be fine. If the SSAS instance is on the same SharePoint server, that is where memory may be a concern.